# Adcash malware removal process, tool

Tags: malware

When I am online, I get always when I unlock the screen a browser popup with a specified address: adcash.com/...
It is just a blank page, but very annoying.
I have tried all the Play offers and highly recommended apps, but it is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have this issue, and it has just started in the last week.

Do you by any chance have an HTC device?

Edit - I've been uninstalling apps one by one, and the removal that seemed to stop it was Ad Block Plus.